# Payumoney response hash mismatch

Tags: php, android, payumoney

I am trying to integrate payumoney with android and php as back end. But after transaction completed, the response hash mismatch with the generated hash from php server.

Android code

```
builder.setAmount(amount)                         
                .setTxnId(txn)                     
                .setPhone(mobile)                   
                .setProductName(product)                   
                .setFirstName(fname)                              
                .setEmail(email)              
                .setsUrl(surl)
                .setfUrl(furl)
                .setUdf1(udf1)
                .setUdf2("")
                .setUdf3("")
                .setUdf4("")
                .setUdf5("")
                .setUdf6("")
                .setUdf7("")
                .setUdf8("")
                .setUdf9("")
                .setUdf10("")
                .setIsDebug(true) 
                .setKey(Common.MERCHANT_KEY) 
                .setMerchantId(Common.MERCHANT_ID);

try {
    paymentParam = builder.build();
    // hash is generated in php server and return it to android app with txnId
    paymentParam.setMerchantHash(hash);
    PayUmoneyFlowManager.startPayUMoneyFlow(paymentParam, StartPaymentActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme_default, false);


} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, " errors "+e.toString());
}
```

PHP code to generate transaction hash

```
$hash=hash('sha512',key.'|'.txnid.'|'.amount.'|'.pinfo.'|'.fname.'|'
        .email.'|'.udf1.'||||||||||'.salt);
```

PHP code to generate response hash

```
$responseHashSeq = SALT.'|'.status.'||||||||||'.udf1.'|'.email.'|'.firstname.'|'.productinfo.'|'.amount.'|'.txnid.'|'.MERCHANT_KEY;
```

I have also tried below code as mentioned in the Payumoney document to generate response hash

```
$responseHashSeq = SALT.'|'.status.'|'.udf1.'||||||'.email.'|'.firstname.'|'.productinfo.'|'.amount.'|'.txnid.'|'.MERCHANT_KEY;
```

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

how about trying same sequence that u tried to genearate

$responseHashSeq = MERCHANT_KEY.'|'.txnid.'|'amount'|'pinfo'|'fname'|'email'|'udf1'|||||||||||'.salt;

Comment: The response hash sequence should be reverse of transaction hash sequence  as mentioned in the Payumoney document. Check the link: https://developer.payumoney.com/android/